# one to zero or one Entityframework navigation property null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an context with one to zero or one relationship in entity Framework.
but when i load my entity it will not load the related entity. It allways be null.

Here is my classes:

```
public class Timerow
    {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int BestNo { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int PosNo { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int EmpNo { get; set; }
            public virtual TimerowOvertime TimerowOvertimes { get; set; }
}

public class TimerowOvertime
    {
            [Key]
            [ForeignKey("Timerow")]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public float Hours { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Transfered { get; set; }
            public bool Weekend { get; set; }
            public bool ATF { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public virtual Timerow Timerow { get; set; }
}
```

But when i try to select Timerow and the related timerowOvertimes, timerowOvertimes allways be null.

i try this:

```
    var timeRows = db.Timerows.ToList();

    foreach (var timeRow in timeRows)
                {
    TimeSheet modelRow = new TimeSheet
                    {
                        Id = timeRow.Id,
                        Date = timeRow.Date,
                        BestNo = timeRow.BestNo,
                        PosNo = timeRow.PosNo,
                        Comment = timeRow.Comment,
                        Hours = timeRow.Hours,
                        Ready = timeRow.Ready,
                        SkillsNoId = timeRow.SkillsNoId
                    };

     if(timeRow.TimerowOvertimes == null)
                    {
                        modelRow.ATF = false;
                        modelRow.Weekend = false;
                        modelRow.Overtime = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        modelRow.Overtime = timeRow.TimerowOvertimes.Hours;
                        modelRow.ATF = timeRow.TimerowOvertimes.ATF;
                        modelRow.Weekend = timeRow.TimerowOvertimes.Weekend;
                    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: do you have data in TimerowOvertimes?

Comment: Try this: `var timeRows = db.Timerows.Include("TimerowOvertimes").ToList();`

Comment: Do you have lazy loading turned off in your DbContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `Id` property in `TimerowOvertime` annotated both as `[Key]` and `[ForeignKey]`. Currently it looks to bind the `Timerow` by using the primary key of `TimerowOvertime` entity. So you need to extend the `TimerowOverTime` entity to contain `TimerowId` property and annotate it with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute.

```
        [ForeignKey("Timerow")]
        public int TimerowId { get; set; }
```